# Using string primary key in database first entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

I am having a requirement to use the existing database to develop my .NET application. The tables in the dB are using string type primary key. Is there a way to implement this with Entity framework? If not, what are the alternative ways which can be used to serve the purpose?

My .net framework is 4.0, using entity framework 6.0.

Comment: Add the [Key] tag above the property that is your key. EF will handle it.

Comment: I won’t be able to modify the model as this is a database first approach.

Comment: You want to operate(CURD) the database with .net in application ?

Comment: @xiehongguang Yes, i need to do CRUD operations

Answer (score 0):

Example base on SQlServer with .NET (using GUID type primary key)

insert data  :

```
            SqlConnection conn = connectLocaldb.ConnectDataBase();
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "INSERT INTO MemberCommitBeforeCompiling(Username,ProjectName,Version,GroupName,CommitTime,Branch) VALUES ('" + push.user_name + "','" + push.project.name + "','" + push.after + "','" + groupname + "',getdate(),'" + push.@ref + "') ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

method to get data :

```
public int GetData(string username, string projectname, int queryDays)
{
    queryDays--;
    //连接本地数据库
    SqlConnection conn = connectLocaldb.ConnectDataBase();
    //打开数据库
    conn.Open();
    //创建查询语句
    SqlCommand querySingleInfo = conn.CreateCommand();
    querySingleInfo.CommandText = "SELECT count(commitid) as times  FROM MemberCommitBeforeCompiling,member where MemberCommitBeforeCompiling.UserName=" + "'" + username + "'  and MemberCommitBeforeCompiling.ProjectName=" + "'" + projectname + "' and MemberCommitBeforeCompiling.username=Member.Username  AND DATEADD(d,-" + queryDays + ", CONVERT(varchar(12), getdate(), 111)) <=CONVERT(varchar(12), CommitTime, 111)";
    SqlDataReader singleInfoReader = querySingleInfo.ExecuteReader();
    //有多行数据，用while循环
    while (singleInfoReader.Read())
    {
        pushTotalOfProject = int.Parse(singleInfoReader["times"].ToString().Trim());
    }
    //关闭查询
    singleInfoReader.Close();
    //关闭数据库连接
    conn.Close();
    return pushTotalOfProject;
}
```

method to update data:

```
    public bool GetUpdateUserRank(string username, int rank)
{
    bool flag = false;
    try
    {
        //连接本地数据库
        SqlConnection conn = connectLocaldb.ConnectDataBase();
        //打开数据库
        conn.Open();
        //创建查询语句
        SqlCommand querySingleInfo = conn.CreateCommand();
        querySingleInfo.CommandText = "Update Member set Rank=" + "'" + rank + "'where username=" + "'" + username + "' ";
        SqlDataReader userRankInfo = querySingleInfo.ExecuteReader();
        //关闭查询
        userRankInfo.Close();
        //关闭数据库连接
        conn.Close();
        flag = true;
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

method to delete data  :

```
public bool GetDeleteGroup(string groupName)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = connectLocaldb.ConnectDataBase();
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "delete MemberGroup where GroupName=" + "'" + groupName + "";
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            flag = true;
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Those are my demo program。Use `Parameters()`method to prevent SQL injection